# Problems when using Entity Framework 6 and SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I was using VS2015 with EntityFramework 6 for mapping my SQL Server 2012 database with database first method. Everything worked fine until upgrade the SQL Server to 2016 version.

Now, when I update my database model Visual Studio crash. The only way I can update my EDMX is using SQL2016 with compatibility mode to 2012 version. With compatibility mode the update works fine. Anyone knows if are there differences between SQL2012 and SQL2016 that may cause this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating Entity Framework EDMX Models After Database Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41069105/updating-entity-framework-edmx-models-after-database-migration)